# How can I subdivide a face which is next to a face that is already subdivided?

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

I want to subdivide a face whose neighbour's faces are subdivided.

Here is an example of such a face:

[image: example]

How can I subdivide selected faces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As these are ngons, you aren't able to use neither Loopcut, nor <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide*. So you can do that in 2 ways:

1. Select ngon's edge in the bottom and subdivide it. Use then <kbd>J</kbd> to connect vertices and split faces.

[image]

2. Press <kbd>K</kbd> to activate [Knife Tool](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html?highlight=knife%20tool). By clicking <kbd>LMB</kbd> you mark places where vertice will be placed.

[image]